# How to display Array value inside UITableviewCell

Tags: json, swift

I have an array called diziTum

```
diziTumm
```

which contains the result

```
  {
   "YASSINIRLA" : "True",
    "KARBON" : "98"
  }
  {
   "YASSINIRLA" : "True",
    "KARBON" : "98"
  }
  {
   "YASSINIRLA" : "True",
    "KARBON" : "98"
  }
```

now I Have a question?
   How can i display the value of "KARBON" in  tableviewCell

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `diziTumm` prints your desired result?

Comment: You can't even spell your own array. What is your question?

Comment: I want to print the value karbon

Comment: you can print 98 by cell.lblSonText.text = diziTumm[indexPath.row]["KARBON"] ?? ""

Answer (score 1):

You should add a cast to the value get from the dictionary in your array diziTumm.

```
cell.lblSonText.text = diziTumm[indexPath.row]["KARBON"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

"Karbon" is a key for value "98"
you can not print the key.

```
cell.lblSonText.text = diziTumm[indexPath.row]["KARBON"] as? String
```

this will print 98

Comment: Force-casting an optional value out of a dictionary is a bad idea.

Comment: i know, but if he tries with optional he won't understand nothing.